# Как решить проблему с адаптивной версткой?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, bootstrap, адаптивная-верстка

Используется *бутстраповский* [шаблон](http://ui-cloud.com/squadfree-free-bootstrap-template-for-creative). Он был натянут на *wordpress* и дальше я принялся его редактировать.

На сайте необходимо в первой секции сделать у `<div>` фоном видео. Там, где стандартно фоном стоит изображение гор. Перепробовал массу вариантов. Проблема в том, чтобы сделать видео растянутым на всю ширину страницы и сделать этот блок адаптивным.

В идеале надо просто у блока вместо изображения фоном поставить видео.

На данный момент у меня получилось вот что:

```css
.intro {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  /*z-index: -2;*/
  /*background: url(../img/bg1.jpg) no-repeat top center;*/
}
#intro.intro {
  padding: 0 0 0 0;
}
.intro .slogan {
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  left: 25%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.flex-video {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 25px;
  padding-bottom: 67.5%;
  height: 0;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: -1;
}
.flex-video.widescreen {
  padding-bottom: 57.25%;
}
.flex-video.vimeo {
  padding-top: 0;
}
.flex-video iframe,
.flex-video object,
.flex-video embed {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 800px),
only screen and (device-width: 1024px) and (device-height: 600px),
only screen and (width: 1280px) and (orientation: landscape),
only screen and (device-width: 800px),
only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .flex-video {
    padding-top: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="span8">
    <div class="flex-video widescreen" style="margin: 0 auto;text-align:center;">
      <div class="slogan">
        <h2>WELCOME TO <span class="text_color">SQUAD</span> </h2>
        <h4>WE ARE GROUP OF GENTLEMEN MAKING AWESOME WEB WITH BOOTSTRAP</h4>
      </div>
      <iframe allowfullscreen="" src="http://i.istockimg.com/video_passthrough/55502676/153/55502676.mp4" frameborder="0">
      </iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Блок, действительно, адаптивный, и заполняет всю ширину страницы, но он серого цвета, а видео в центре в маленьком разрешении.

[image: Результат]

Если его уменьшать, то все адаптивно уменьшается. Но почему он не увеличивается до большого размера? Дело в маленьком разрешении видео?

И еще вопрос. Текст, который сейчас находится над видео («Welcome to squad» и т.д.) должен находиться поверх блока с видео, как в оригинальном шаблоне, но уползло наверх. Как это исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет времени использовать вашу css верстку, вот мой вариант

```js
/** Document Ready Functions **/
/********************************************************************/

$(document).ready(function() {

  // Resive video
  scaleVideoContainer();

  initBannerVideoSize('.video-container .poster img');
  initBannerVideoSize('.video-container .filter');
  initBannerVideoSize('.video-container video');

  $(window).on('resize', function() {
    scaleVideoContainer();
    scaleBannerVideoSize('.video-container .poster img');
    scaleBannerVideoSize('.video-container .filter');
    scaleBannerVideoSize('.video-container video');
  });

});

/** Reusable Functions **/
/********************************************************************/

function scaleVideoContainer() {

  var height = $(window).height();
  var unitHeight = parseInt(height) + 'px';
  $('.homepage-hero-module').css('height', unitHeight);

}

function initBannerVideoSize(element) {

  $(element).each(function() {
    $(this).data('height', $(this).height());
    $(this).data('width', $(this).width());
  });

  scaleBannerVideoSize(element);

}

function scaleBannerVideoSize(element) {

  var windowWidth = $(window).width(),
    windowHeight = $(window).height(),
    videoWidth,
    videoHeight;

  console.log(windowHeight);

  $(element).each(function() {
    var videoAspectRatio = $(this).data('height') / $(this).data('width'),
      windowAspectRatio = windowHeight / windowWidth;

    if (videoAspectRatio > windowAspectRatio) {
      videoWidth = windowWidth;
      videoHeight = videoWidth * videoAspectRatio*1.25;
      $(this).css({
        'top': -(videoHeight - windowHeight) / 2 + 'px',
        'margin-left': 0
      });
    } else {
      videoHeight = windowHeight * 1.25;
      videoWidth = videoHeight / videoAspectRatio;
      $(this).css({
        'margin-top': 0,
        'margin-left': -(videoWidth - windowWidth) / 2 + 'px'
      });
    }

    $(this).width(videoWidth).height(videoHeight);

    $('.homepage-hero-module .video-container video').addClass('fadeIn animated');


  });
}
```

```css
.homepage-hero-module {
  border-right: none;
  border-left: none;
  position: relative;
}
.no-video .video-container video,
.touch .video-container video {
  display: none;
}
.no-video .video-container .poster,
.touch .video-container .poster {
  display: block !important;
}
.video-container {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #000;
}
.video-container video {
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}
.video-container .poster img {
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
.video-container .filter {
  z-index: 100;
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  width: 100%;
}
.video-container .title-container {
  z-index: 1000;
  position: absolute;
  top: 35%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}
.video-container .description .inner {
  font-size: 1em;
  width: 45%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.video-container .link {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 3em;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 1001;
  font-size: 2em;
  color: #fff;
}
.video-container .link a {
  color: #fff;
}
.video-container video {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
.video-container video.fillWidth {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="homepage-hero-module">
  <div class="video-container">
    <div class="title-container">
      <div class="headline">
        <h2>WELCOME TO <span class="text_color">SQUAD</span> </h2>
      </div>
      <h4>WE ARE GROUP OF GENTLEMEN MAKING AWESOME WEB WITH BOOTSTRAP</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="filter"></div>
    <video autoplay loop class="fillWidth">
      <source src="http://i.istockimg.com/video_passthrough/55502676/153/55502676.mp4" type="video/mp4" />Your browser does not support the video tag. I suggest you upgrade your browser.</video>
    <div class="poster hidden">
      <img src="http://www.videojs.com/img/poster.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, основную проблему решает. У меня проблема как раз в том, что с js проблемы. :) А такой вопрос. Там всё равно остается рамка черная по краям. Возможно ли исправить как-то? Чтобы было растянуто на весь блок. Может у самого видео сделать отрицательный padding или что-то вроде?

Comment: @KuznetsovMaxim Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа). Если у Вас возник новый вопрос, задайте его при помощи кнопки "[Задать вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)". Если нужно указать контекст, дайте ссылку на этот вопрос.

Comment: Дан не исчерпывающий ответ. Поставленная задача полностью не решена. Дабы не плодить одинаковые вопросы, я надеюсь, что смогу решить проблему в этом вопросе. @sashatexb разбирается в вопросе, надеюсь, получится до конца добить)

Comment: ну сейчас должно работать так как Вы хотели

Comment: Спасибо большое, @sashatexb , я твой должник) Проблема решена, все работает)

Comment: гуд) все пожалуйста, самому было интересно